# Trying to assign a value from a querystring to a Shopify line item property

Tags: javascript, html, query-string, shopify, liquid

**HTML**

```
 <div>
    <input type="hidden" id="shirtImg" name="properties[ShirtImg]"/>
 </div>

 <div id="purchase" onclick="createLineItemProperties()">
            <p class="price"></p>                                 
            <input class="btn" type="submit" name="add" id="add-to-cart" value="Add to Cart" />
 </div>
```

This code is in product.liquid. All of this is wrapped in the /cart/add form tag.

**Javascript**

```
 function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
    vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
```

}

```
function createLineItemProperties() {
   if(getUrlVars()["side1"] != null){
      console.log("inside if statement");
      document.getElementById("shirtImg").value = getUrlVars()["side1"];
   }
console.log(document.getElementById("shirtImg").value);
}
```

Here the javascript is pulling a value called "side1" from the query string. The console.log there actually ends up printing the result that I want, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to get saved in the line item property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that running that function when "add to cart" was clicked was a bad idea, because it ended up sending the form data first and then reassigning the id after, leaving me with an undesired result. I just called that function through the body tag's onload event instead and now it works.